# Convert Activity to a simple one button Facebook 3.0 Login

Tags: android, session, authentication, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Been banging my head against the walls for just short of a week trying to wrap my head around Facebooks newest SDK for Android ( 3.0 ) , Seems to me Facebook has managed to overcomplicate something that wasnt broken in the first place.

All I want to do is make the code from onCreate work from onClick.The code for the activity ive written to get this far is below and yes, it does currently work upon launching. (logs a user in ,makes a request to my api and does what its suppose to. )

I dont need nor do I want to manage Facebooks "sessions" anymore than I absolutely have to , I simply want to let a user login using their fb credentials , open up a session , make a single request to grab the users info , send it up to my API and takeover using my own API/shared prefs/sessions. If its easier to point me in the direction of a snippet that would illustrate how i could do this w. the permissions ive set below vs. editing my activity that would more than answer my question as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

public class Old_FB_Login_Activity extends Activity {
    private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";

    private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;
    private Button buttonLoginLogout;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
 // List of additional write permissions being requested
    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email","user_about_me","user_activities",
    "user_birthday","user_education_history", "user_events","user_hometown", "user_groups","user_interests","user_likes",
    "user_location","user_photos","user_work_history");

    SharedPrefs sharedprefs;
    // Request code for reauthorization requests.
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

    // Flag to represent if we are waiting for extended permissions
    private boolean pendingAnnounce = false;
    protected String college;
    private Button buttonLogin; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebooklogin); 
        buttonLoginLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginLogout);
        buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        textInstructionsOrLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.instructionsOrLink);
        sharedprefs = new SharedPrefs(getApplicationContext());  

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS));
            }
        }

        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Log.i("permissions",session.getPermissions().toString());
            //makeLikesRequest(session);
            makeMeRequest(session);

            Log.i("token",session.getAccessToken());
            Log.i("token experation", session.getExpirationDate().toString());




            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FaceTestActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            /*buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.logout);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
            });*/
        } else {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText(R.string.instructions);
            buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.login);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS));
        } else {

            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogout() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    } 

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        } 
    }

   /* private void makeLikesRequest(final Session session) {
        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // response should have the likes

                 // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {

                    Log.i("likes response", response.toString());
                }

            }
        };
        Request request = new Request(session, "me/likes", null, HttpMethod.GET, callback);
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    } */


    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a 
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // If the response is successful
                if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                        // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                        Log.i("user", user.toString());
                        JSONObject json = user.getInnerJSONObject();
                        Log.i("json me response", json.toString());

                        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

                        String fb_token = session.getAccessToken().toString();
                        String fb_token_expires = session.getExpirationDate().toString();
                        Log.i("fb_token", fb_token);
                        params.put("fb_token",fb_token);
                        Log.i("fb_token_expires", fb_token_expires);
                        params.put("fb_token_expires",fb_token_expires);



                        if(user.getBirthday() != null){
                            String birthday = user.getBirthday();
                            Log.i("birthday_1",birthday);
                            params.put("birthday", birthday);
                        }

                        if(user.getFirstName() != null){
                            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                            Log.i("first name_2", firstName);
                            params.put("first_name", firstName);
                        }


                        if(user.getLastName() != null){
                            String lastName = user.getLastName();
                            Log.i("last name_3", lastName);
                            params.put("last_name", lastName);
                        }  

                        if(user.getLink() != null){
                            String fb_link = user.getLink();
                            Log.i("fb_link_4", fb_link);
                            params.put("fb_link", fb_link);
                        }

                        if(user.getId() != null){
                            String fb_uid = user.getId();
                            Log.i("fb uid_5", fb_uid);
                            params.put("fb_uid", fb_uid);
                        }


                        if(user.getProperty("gender") != null){
                            String gender = user.getProperty("gender").toString();
                            Log.i("gender_6", gender);
                            params.put("gender", gender);
                        }

                        if(user.getProperty("email") != null){
                            String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
                            Log.i("email_7", email);
                            params.put("fb_email", email);
                        }


                        if(user.getProperty("verified") != null){
                            String verified = user.getProperty("verified").toString();
                            Log.i("verified_8", verified);
                            params.put("verified", verified);

                        }


                        if(user.getProperty("bio") != null){
                            String bio = user.getProperty("bio").toString();
                            Log.i("bio_9", bio);
                            params.put("bio", bio);

                        }
                        if(user.getLocation().getProperty("name") != null){

                            String location = user.getLocation().getProperty("name").toString();
                            Log.i("location_10", location);
                            params.put("location", location);

                        } 


                        //user Location
                        JSONArray education_array = (JSONArray)user.getProperty("education");
                        if (education_array.length() > 0) {
                            String education_length= String.valueOf(education_array.length());
                            Log.i("education_length",education_length);
                            ArrayList<String> collegeNames = new ArrayList<String> ();
                            for (int i=0; i < education_array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject edu_obj = education_array.optJSONObject(i);


                                // Add the language name to a list. Use JSON
                                // methods to get access to the name field.

                              String type = edu_obj.optString("type");
                              Log.i("type of edu", type);
                              if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("college")){
                                  JSONObject school_obj = edu_obj.optJSONObject("school");
                                  college = school_obj.optString("name");
                                  //Log.i("college",college);



                              }


                            }  
                            params.put("college", college);
                            Log.i("college", college);

                        }


                        RestClient.post(FB_LOGIN_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, JSONObject arg1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);

                                Log.i("FAILED TO LOGIN:", arg1.toString());
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg1.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {

                                Log.i("Login Request Success:", json.toString());

                                    try {
                                        sharedprefs.createFBLoginSession(json);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabHostFragmentActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    finish();



                            }
                        });










                    }
                }
                if (response.getError() != null) {
                    // Handle errors, will do so later.
                }
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you want to look at is UiLifecycleHelper, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/UiLifecycleHelper/. You simply create an instance of this in your activity's onCreate method and pass an instance of Session.StatusCallback to handle the changes in session state (opened, closed, etc). Then you insert calls to UiLifecycleHelper in several of the activity's lifecycle methods (onCreate, onResume, etc.).  That should replace all of the stuff that the old FacebookActivity used to do.

Then just use the LoginButton to kick off the login process https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/LoginButton.

Comment: Hey @Matt I tried implementing the FB login flow with the UILifeCycleHelper and in certain instances, the `data` param which would normally have a field `mMap`, which contains the FB response, is null.  Why would this be happening?